# Two Face offers Batman a game of chance

Tags: probability

Two Face offers Batman a game of chance, where he tosses a coin and will punch him if the result is “heads”.

However, the coin is not fair and has some probability $p$ of landing as “heads”.

a. Develop an expression* for the standard deviation of the number of times Two Face will punch Batman per a single coin toss, as a function of $p$.

b. What is the value of the standard deviation when $p=0.1$, $p=0.5$ and $p=0.9$?

Comment: The largest variance is when p = 1/2 when $p(1-p)$ is maximized. If p is 0 or 1 then variance is 0 (never punched or always punched).

Comment: What is the distribution of the random variable X:  Number of times Two Face will punch Batman per a single coin toss ?

Comment: yes, per single coin toss

Comment: For future reference, posts that appear to be simple cut-and-paste exercises are very likely to be downvoted and/or closed.  If an exercise is assigned to you, you should at least attempt the problem before posting here and use that attempt to add "context" to the post beyond the mere restatement of the problem.  For example, are there similar exercises which you already saw worked, or does the exercise seem intended to reinforce material you recently covered?  While evident to you this sort of context can only be guessed at by Readers without your contribution.

Comment: well, first of all, i'm sorry for the copy-paste. i did tried to solve the question and i needed a validation. the reason i copy paste is because i don't have an equetion editor. why is it importante to you whether i rewrite the question or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of times that Batman gets punched. Then $X$ is a Bernoulli  random variable with parameter $p$, so if we are familiar with the Bernoulli distribution then we might already know the expected value and variance of $X$ by heart.  If not, we can compute them as follows.

The expected value of $X$ is
$$
E(X) = p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0 = p.
$$
The variance of $X$ is $\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$.
Note that
$$
E(X^2) = p \cdot 1^2 + (1 - p) \cdot 0^2 = p.
$$
Thus,
$$
\text{Var}(X) = p - p^2 = p(1 - p).
$$
The standard deviation of $X$ is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.